# what do "user","system", and "elapsed" times mean in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am adopting parallel computing in R, and doing some benchmark works. I notice that when multiple cores are used, `system.time` shows increased times for `user` and `system`, but the `elapsed` time is decreased. Does this indicate that parallel computing is effective? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the links under "Related" on the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do `help(system.time)` you get a hint to also look at `help(proc.time)`. I quote from its help page:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  An object of class ‘"proc_time"’ which is a numeric vector of
>  length 5, containing the user, system, and total elapsed times for
>  the currently running R process, and the cumulative sum of user
>  and system times of any child processes spawned by it on which it
>  has waited.  (The ‘print’ method uses the ‘summary’ method to
>  combine the child times with those of the main process.)
>
>  The definition of ‘user’ and ‘system’ times is from your OS.
>  Typically it is something like
>
>  _The ‘user time’ is the CPU time charged for the execution of user
>  instructions of the calling process.  The ‘system time’ is the CPU
>  time charged for execution by the system on behalf of the calling
>  process._
>
>  Times of child processes are not available on Windows and will
>  always be given as ‘NA’.
>
>  The resolution of the times will be system-specific and on
>  Unix-alikes times are rounded down to milliseconds.  On modern
>  systems they will be that accurate, but on older systems they
>  might be accurate to 1/100 or 1/60 sec.  They are typically
>  available to 10ms on Windows.
> ```

Comment: What would be a good example of something -- triggered by an R call -- that contributes to 'system' time, but not to 'user' time? And, for concreteness' sake, is there a particular R function that will often incur more cost in 'system' time than in 'user' time?